# Search and replace in string

Tags: c, string, replace, html-entities

How can i do search and replace in C? I'm trying to do function to replace html entities in string. I already have the function to find beginning and end of html entities but i can't figure out how to replace them.

Here is what i have already:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct entity {
    char *entity;
    char *substitute;
};

void replacehtmlentities(char *str, char *dest) {
    int i;
    char *begin = NULL;
    char *end;

    struct entity entities[] = {
        { "&nbsp;", " " },
        { "&lt;", "<" },
        { "&gt;", ">" },
        { "&amp;", "&" },
        { "&euro;", "€" },
        { "&copy;", "©" },
        { "&reg;", "®" },
        { NULL, NULL },
    };

    for (i = 0; entities[i].entity; i++) {
        while (begin = strstr(str, entities[i].entity)) {
            end = begin + strlen(entities[i].entity);
            // how to replace
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *str = "space &nbsp; lowerthan &lt; end";

    printf("%s\n", str);

    replacehtmlentities(str);

    printf("%s\n", str);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is to use an existing string replacement function. There's one on my site at http://creativeandcritical.net/str-replace-c/ (the current version is named `replace_str2`). The changes you'd need to make to your code to use it (tested) are:

- Add `#include <stddef.h>` to the other includes.
- Copy the `replace_str2` function into the file above the `replacehtmlentities` function.
- Change the prototype of the function `replacehtmlentities` to:

  ```
  char *replacehtmlentities(char *str)
  ```
- Add to that function the following variable declarations:

  ```
  char *tmp = NULL;
  char *tmp2 = str;
  ```
- Replace in that function the code:

  ```
      while (begin = strstr(str, entities[i].entity)) {
          end = begin + strlen(entities[i].entity);
          // how to replace
      }
  ```

with:

```
        tmp = replace_str2(tmp2, entities[i].entity, entities[i].substitute);
        if (i) free(tmp2);
        tmp2 = tmp;
```

- Add a final return to that function:

  ```
  return tmp2;
  ```
- In main, change your call of that function to:

  ```
  str = replacehtmlentities(str);
  ```

As an additional note: in main, str will now reference memory allocated with malloc. If/when you no longer require this string, you can free the memory by calling free(str).

Answer (score 2):

The pointer `str` points to a string literal, and string literals are *read only* (i.e. constant). Trying to modify a string literal will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The solution is very simple: Declare `str` as an array:

```
char str[] = "space &nbsp; lowerthan &lt; end";
```

However be careful when replacing sequences in a string, so you don't replace a shorter sub-string with a longer, as then you might write beyond the end of the string.